# Image Upload with Preview and Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

Have the followig questions and need answers regarding the following script that will Preview a Photo before upload. The script is from http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/edit#javascript,html

1) The script works for Firefox, no good for IE. How to make it works for IE?

2) It does not have a method to delete the photo. Needs something like a small image "X" installed on the Preview Photo, clicking this "X" will delete the photo. Can anyone supply this solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting on IE ?

Comment: Yeah, can you provide some more information or post an example into http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 6):

[**Demo**](http://plungjan.name/test/previewjq.html)

Tested on several browsers, Chrome, Fx, Safari 6 (could someone test 5?)

Works on my IE8 on XP without any changes in settings but as @Gunasekaran mentions later on this page you may need to

> Open Tools->internet option-> security tab-> custom level - locate the setting "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" and click on Enable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Image preview</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var blank="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Blank.gif";
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
      var img = input.value;
        $('#img_prev').attr('src',img).height(200);
    }
    $("#x").show().css("margin-right","10px");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#img_prev").attr("src",blank);
    $("#x").hide();  
  });
});
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
#x { display:none; position:relative; z-index:200; float:right}
#previewPane { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /><br/>
<span id="previewPane">
<img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
<span id="x">[X]</span>
</span>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Looks like this in IE8 on XP:

[image: Example]

A newer method is [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) which I have not implemented

*Update* You will need to add an onclick to clear the file input if you want to allow the user to select the same image twice (onchange does not trigger then)

[HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

Comment: Sorry, your solution does not work. Tested it on IE8, and it did not work.

Comment: Uploaded a new demo and updated the code. Works including the hide button - for me IE8 XP, FX 10

Comment: Sorry, tried your code on my IE8 but still not working, see the Screen Shot of my IE8 for your code: http://www.asuma.com/user1231/ss-120418.jpg  The preview pic appeared as a broken image.

Comment: What version on what platform?

Comment: IE8 Version:8.0.6001.18702 Windows XP

Comment: Can you add plungjan.name to trusted sites? - You can remove it again after testing. I will not harm your browser...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your request of adding plungjan.name to trusted sites. Advise me how to do it.

Comment: Since it will likely allow what you want and is also likely the only difference between your IE8 and mine. Here is how http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Add_a_Site_to_Trusted_Sites_76851969

Comment: Done. By the way, your demo site also doesn't work for my IE8. It shows a broken image.

Comment: I cannot help you. Works perfectly on my IE8 on XP. Did you try other images?

Comment: Hi, I found a bug. After you click [X] you can't add previous image again. Only new. How to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file - I updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will not work on anything less that Internet Explorer 10 ... `FileReader()` support isn't introduced until IE10 .. it will work with Chrome 7 and Firefox 3.6

[See the docs for support of FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) or [caniuse.com here](http://caniuse.com/filereader)

Comment: Sorry, your answer does not work. Tested it on IE 8 and it did not work.

Comment: @user1315468 im slightly confused ... In my answer I told you it will not work in IE8 ... see the links I added

Comment: Sorry, I provided an incorrect comment. Any solutions for older Browsers?

Comment: @user1315468 just a quick google returns this -> http://code.google.com/p/image-upload-preview/ (never used it before but says it supports IE8

Comment: However the DEMO link is dead

Comment: @mplungjan you are right ...any better (working) alternatives ?

Comment: Mine on this page - it does not work on OPs browser but works on mine. Does it work on yours too?

Comment: There is another part of the script for browsers without filereader support. Look at the code. Can you try it in IE please?

Answer (score 1):

In reply to last response of @user1315468
IE8 needs a security settings change:

Open Tools->internet option-> security tab-> custom level 
locate the setting "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" and click on Enable.

After this change, you can reopen the browser with mplungjan's demo link.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**I have Pasted the complete working code for all browsers..

NOTE: sometimes Internet Explorer may block scripts,so inorder to view the image click on the prompt and "Allow blocked content".Below is the working code...**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="form2">

<div>
<input type="file"  name="myFile"   id="myFile" onchange="readURL(this);"></input>
</div>

<div>
<img id="previewImg" src="#" />
</div>

</form>
<script>

function readURL(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#previewImg')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .width(130);
    }
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

}else{
          var filename = "";
         filename = "file:\/\/"+input.value;
         document.form2.previewImg.src=filename;
         document.form2.previewImg.style.width="130px";

 }
}
 </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: previewImg is not accessible via document.form2 unless it is <input type="image"

Answer (score 0):

FileReader sounds great to read content of image or file.
But consider that file that you were reading was 20MB big, reading it as dataURL is going to create a JS object which is tat big. How do you avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

`<img  id="img1" alt="" runat="server"/>
<span id="x" ></span> 
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" onchange="readURL(this)" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#imgRepresentImage").attr("src", e.target.result).width(200);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    } else {
        var img = input.value;
        $("#imgRepresentImage").attr("src", img).width(200);
    }
    $("#x").text('[X]');
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#x").click(function () {
        $("#imgRepresentImage").attr("src", "").width(0);
        $("#x").text('');
        $("#representImageUpload").val('');
    });
});
```

Worked for me :)