# Ajax file posting IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

How can I post files using AJAX? Now I'm using formData:

```
    $("#image_upload").change(function() {

        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $form.append('<div class="loading-overlay"><div class="loading-overlay__gif"><img src="/images/preloader.gif" class="loading-overlay__gif" /></div></div>');

        $('#photo-choice-error').remove();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', $(this)[0].files[0]);
        // ...
    });
```

But it doesn't work in some browsers, especially in IE8 and IE9. What can I do instead?

Comment: For the preview have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10206834/295783 which may work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think IE 8/9 have support for `FormData`. AFAIK `FormData` is available from IE 10.

You could instead try using [JQuery Forms](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), which works on IE 8 onwards.

Comment: I thought about that, but in different cases I need to send different parts of my form. And I couldn't find a solution to do that with forms plugin. Did you?

Comment: I don't think I realize your use cases, but surely you could append elements using `$('#formid').append()`. In case you want your form to be immutable, you could `clone` your form and submit it after appending elements?

Comment: It's not about apending elements to the form. In my case, I need to send only one of all inputs, and then - all onother except that first one.